# How to remove an application from OS X Launchpad when it has no X, does not appear in the applications folder, and refuses to go into the trash?

Tags: macos, uninstall, steam, trash, unwanted-application

I wish to remove this application from Launchpad - and preferably Spotlight as well. Screenshots are linked at the bottom of the post. 
I have an application (a game) called `The Bridge` that I initially installed through the Steam (game hub) client. 
I have already uninstalled it using the Steam's provided uninstaller.

The game continues to show up in the Launchpad when I search for a similarly named application despite it no longer launching appropriately, not having an X when I click-and-hold on it, and not seeming to do anything at all when I drag it to the trash.

No reference to this application exists within the Applications folder, so far as I can tell. Spotlight shows the location to be `<me>/Applications/The Bridge`. The screenshot is saying that the location doesn't exist.

How can I make this Launchpad entry go away, short of wiping the whole machine? I'm a techie that just doesn't know the Mac OS very well yet, so I don't mind going in to patch some deep files if that's what's needed.

Thanks much!

Reference Images:
* [Spotlight finds the application at `<me>/Applications/The Bridge`...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oyMm.png)
* [Application is present in Launchpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGf6V.png)
* [Steam showing the game as Not Installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmqk7.png)
* [The application is not in the Applications directory when browsing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlCy9.png)
* [The application is not in the Applications directory when searching.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4YQ8.png)
* (Edit 1:) [Added this `~/Applications` screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSrOB.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mac OS there are basically two Applications folders.  One is off root at `/Applications` and the other is located in you home directory which should be `/Users/yourUser/Applications/`.  Based on your description is sounds like `The Bridge` is installed in the second.

Here is an [article](https://www.engadget.com/2010/12/03/mac-101-the-two-applications-folders/) that describes the two `Applications` folders.

Look in your `${HOME}/` directory for a directory called Applications.

If you are using Finder you can <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-g to open a `Go To Folder:` dialog and enter `~/Applications` to navigate there directly.

Remove any remnants from there.

Empty the trash to ensure all references to the file have been removed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Per your advice, I located and trashed the application from `~/Applications`, and rebooted, though the application still appears in Launchpad and Spotlight.

Comment: Interesting ... went and got the game and installed it.  It put the file into my ~/Applications.  I was able to drag the application from there and put it in the Trash and it disappeared.  Sounds like that is not your experience.  Did you empty the Trash ?  Also, Can you confirm the applciation is not in /Applications nor ~/Applications ?

Comment: Do this: from Launchpad drag "The Bridge" into the dock.  Then right click "The Bridge" in the dock and select via right-click `Options->Show In Finder`.  This should be the directory where the file is located.  From there, you should drag to the trash.

Comment: It's correct that I moved it to the trash and it still remained in Spotlight and Launchpad. The answer seemed to be to empty it from the trash followed by a reboot. I was unaware that the item will still show up until it's been fully deleted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The reasoning behind that is why on Mac it's called 'Finder' not 'Explorer' - it always knows where the file is, even if it's in the trash.